# Periodic orbit property

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, fixed-point-theorems, discrete-dynamical-systems

A topological space $X$ satisfies the "Periodic orbit property", briefly POP, if for every continuous map $f:X \to X$, there exist  a natural number $n$ and  a point $x_{0}\in X$  such that $f^{n}(x_{0})=x_{0}$.

Obviously fixed point property (FPP) implies POP.

For a natural number $n$, a topological space $X$ is  called $n$-POP if for every continuous map $f$ on $X$, $f^{n}$ has a fixed point. (Ex: $\mathbb{S}^{2n}$ is a 2-POP manifold, because the degree of a fixed-point-free map on $\mathbb{S}^{2n}$ must be $-1$.)

The question:

> Is there an example of a manifold $M$ which satisfies POP but for  every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a continuous map $f$ on $M$ such that $f^{n}$ has no fixed point?

Namely: we search for a manifold for which every self-map has a periodic orbit, but there is no any control on periods.

Equivalently:

> Is there a manifold $M$ which is POP but not $n$-POP for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$?

In particular, can we say:

> "every compact POP manifold is necessarily a $n$-POP manifold, for some $n$"?

Motivated by the Lefschetz fixed-point theorem, we ask that:

What algebraic topological criterion, can be introduced for consideration of this property(POP)?

**Edit:** According to the very interesting answer of Qiaochu  Yuan, in the orientable case, the question is equivalent to the following:

> Let M be a closed orientable  manifold. Is it true that $M$ is not  POP if and only if $\chi(M)=0$?

**Note1** For a related question see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136158/does-a-self-map-from-the-wedge-sum-of-two-spheres-have-either-a-fixed-point-or-a) and it is natural to ask that "Does $S^{2}\vee S^{2}$ satisfy the periodic orbit property?"

**Note2** I think the continuation of the argument of Qiaochu Yuan  for his  first statement is  not easy, for arbitrary manifold. Because for the  simplest case $S^{3}$ we had the famous conjecture of "existence of  a vector field on $S^{3}$ without periodic orbit. In fact consideration of non vanishing vector fields is necessary but not sufficient. Periodic orbits of vector fields are important, too. Moreover, perhaps  an approach which is not based on "vector fields" could be useful, for example consideration of orientation-reversing diffeomorphisms.

**Note 3:** "pointwise periodic homeomorphism' is a concept which is indirectly similar to the subject of this post.

Comment: Let  $R_{\alpha}:S^1\to S^1$ be an irrational rotation, then $R^n_{\alpha}$ has no fixed point for every $n\geqslant 1$

Comment: So $S^{1}$ is  not  a POP manifold. But I search for  a  manifold which is  POP but is  not n-POP for  all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What are examples of manifolds that satisfy POP but *not* FPP?

Comment: $S^{2n}$ is an example. The antipodal map has no fixed point, So $S^{2n}$ does not satisfy FPP. On the other hand, if $f$ is  a self map on $S^{2n}$ without fixed point,Then  deg(f)=-1. See Algebraic topology(Allen Hatcher). So deg($f^{2}$)=1. Then $f^{2}$ has fixed point. This shows that for every self map f on $S^{2n}$, $f^{2}$ has a fixed point.

Comment: With regards to your note at the end: A vector field without periodic orbits gives you a map without periodic points, but some vector fields with periodic orbits still have time $1$ maps without periodic orbits. As an example, on $S^3$ viewed as the unit sphere in $\mathbb{C}^2$, the map $(z,w) \mapsto (\lambda z, \lambda w)$ has no periodic points whenever $\lambda = e^{2\pi i \alpha}$ with irrational $\alpha$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer  Yes thank you for the comment. In that end not I tried to change situation in order to find  a possible counter example in oriention reversing diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 24):

Nice question! Here's what I can show.

> Let $X$ be a smooth closed manifold. Then:
>
> (1) If $\chi(X) = 0$, then $X$ is not $n$-POP for any $n$.
>
> (2) If $\chi(X) \neq 0$ and $X$ is orientable, then $X$ is $\text{lcm}(1, 2, ... n)$-POP with respect to maps $f : X \to X$ of nonzero degree, where $n = \text{max}(b_0 + b_2 + ..., b_1 + b_3 + ...)$ (where $b_i$ is the $i^{th}$ Betti number of $X$).

*Proof of 1.* We will use the converse of the Poincaré-Hopf theorem: if $\chi(X) = 0$, then $X$ admits a nonvanishing vector field. Let $\varphi(t)$ denote the flow of this vector field. Let $t_{0}>0$ be small enough so that $\varphi(t_0)$ has no fixed points. Such $t_{0}$ exists, because there  is  a positive uniform lower bound  for the period of  all periodic orbits.(As  a  consequence  of the flow  box theorem, around regular points  of a vector field). For a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $f = \varphi \left( \frac{t_0}{n} \right)$. Then $f^n$ has no fixed points, hence $X$ is not $n$-POP. $\Box$

(I strongly suspect that in this case $X$ is not POP either; it seems like we should be able to consider a small flow of a sufficiently generic nonvanishing vector field. But I don't know how to finish this argument.)

*Proof of 2.* We will need the following two observations.

**Lemma 1:** Let $f_0, f_1$ be linear operators acting on two finite-dimensional vector spaces $V_0, V_1$. If $\text{tr}(f_0^k) = \text{tr}(f_1^k)$ for $k$ between $1$ and $\text{max}(\dim V_0, \dim V_1)$, then $f_0$ and $f_1$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues with the same multiplicities.

*Proof.* The above condition implies, using the Newton-Girard identities, that $f_0$ and $f_1$ have the same characteristic polynomial up to factors of $t$. $\Box$

**Lemma 2:** Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensional smooth closed oriented manifold and let $f : X \to X$ be a map of nonzero degree. Then every eigenvalue of $f$ acting on cohomology (with complex coefficients) is nonzero.

*Proof.*  Let $e_1, ..., e_d$ be a basis of generalized eigenvectors for the action of $f$ on $H^k(X, \mathbb{C})$. By Poincaré duality the cup product $H^k \otimes H^{n-k} \to H^n$ is nondegenerate, so we can find a dual basis $e_1^{\ast}, ..., e_d^{\ast}$ of $H^{n-k}(X, \mathbb{C})$. Since $f$ acts by a nonzero scalar, namely $\deg f$, on $e_i \smile e_i^{\ast}$ for all $i$, the generalized eigenvalue of $e_i$ must also be nonzero. $\Box$

Now back to the proof of 2. With hypotheses as above, let $f_0$ denote the map induced by $f$ on the direct sum $V_0$ of the even-dimensional complex cohomology of $X$ and let $f_1$ denote the map induced by $f$ on the direct sum $V_1$ of the odd-dimensional complex cohomology of $X$, so that the Lefschetz trace of $f^k$ can be written

$$L(f^k) = \text{tr}(f_0^k) - \text{tr}(f_1^k).$$

By Lemma 2, the eigenvalues of $f_0$ and $f_1$ are all nonzero, so if $f_0$ and $f_1$ have the same nonzero eigenvalues then in particular $\dim V_0 = \dim V_1$. By the contrapositive of Lemma 1, if $\chi(X) = \dim V_0 - \dim V_1 \neq 0$, then there exists some $k$ between $1$ and $n = \text{max}(\dim V_0, \dim V_1)$ such that $L(f^k) \neq 0$, hence, by the Lefschetz fixed point theorem, such that $f^k$ has a fixed point. In particular, $f^{\text{lcm}(1, 2, ... n)}$ has a fixed point. $\Box$

Comment: For $1$, it is sufficient to check that a sufficiently generic vector field has countably many loops. Then there is a real number that is not a rational multiple of the period of any loop.

Comment: @Will: cool. How would I check that? My differential geometry is quite poor.

Comment: So is mine! I was hoping that someone who knows more differential geometry than me would read it.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thank you very much for your  interesting answer, WillSawin thank you for your useful comment. But just  two question:1)why a generic vector field posses infinit number of closed orbits? For example, Is not a situation similar to Kuperberge Counter example to Seifert conjecture, a generic situation? 2)according to your comment , we need to be sure that we have a countable closed orbit.(How you can control this countability?

Comment: For $\dim X=3$ you can always equip a contact 1-form $\lambda$ and speak about the Reeb vector field $R$, satisfying $\lambda(R)=1$ and $d\lambda(R,\cdot)=0$. "Loops" here are called Reeb orbits (and these exist by Taubes' proof of the Weinstein conjecture), and for generic $\lambda$ all Reeb orbits are "cut out transversely", and in particular are isolated. For example, the Hopf fibration depicts the Reeb flow on $(S^3,\lambda=\sum x_idy_i-y_idx_i)$ whose orbits are the $S^1$-fibers, and perturbing this contact form will break that foliation.

Comment: For anyone who's still thinking about this, this seems silly but I can't think of an example of a endomap of degree $0$ without fixed points. All of the examples of maps of degree $0$ I can think of are projection maps $M \times N \to M \times \{ n \}$, which fix $n \in N$. Any ideas?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan for spheres or $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ your statement is true, because the lifschets index is non zero if the degree of f iz zero(in these particular case sphere or CP^n)

Comment: I think your question is interesting:"an example of a fixed point free map with zero degree"

Comment: @Ali: yes, the same is true for any smooth compact manifold such that each of its homology groups has rank at most $1$. But there are many maps of nonzero Lefschetz index but zero degree among, say, endomorphisms of tori. (All the ones I can write down have fixed points though.)

Comment: @Qiaochu I think the following map on tori has no fixed point and its degree is zero: Define $g$ on$\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with $f(x,y)=(1/2+x,0)$. Note that $\mathbb{T}^{2}=\mathbb{R}^{2}/ \mathbb{Z}^{2}$. Put f= the quotient map. It can be shown that deg(f)=0, since there is a generator in $H^{1}$ which is sent to zero with $f^{*}$. On the other hand the cup product of generators of $H^{1}$ is a generator for $H^{2}$

Comment: More generally, assume that $M$ is  a manifold and $f$ is  a  map on $M$  without fixed point. Fix a point $y_{0}\in M$, Then $F:M\times M \to M\times M$  with $F=(f,y_{0})$ is  another example

Comment: @Ali: cool. Do you have an example which in addition has nonzero Euler characteristic?

Comment: @Qiaochu yes in my previous comment Put $M=S^{2}$ and f=antipod, then $\chi (M\times M)=4$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan there is  a counterexample  of two manifold with FPP but their product is not. I confess that I do not know the technical construction But I am curious to know whether their product is POP? did you read the technical construction of this counterexample?

Answer (score 5):

The following is proved by
F. Brock Fuller in "The Existence of Periodic Points," Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 57, 1953, pp. 229-230:

**Theorem.** Let X be a  compact simplicial complex with  Betti numbers $B_i$, and nonzero Euler characteristic. If a continuous map
 $f: X\rightarrow X$ induces isomorphisms of homology groups, then $f$ has a point whose period is $\le \max_i \big (∑_i B_{2i},∑_i B_{2i-1} \big)$. Thus every homeomorphism of $X$ has a periodic orbit.

Comment: This can be proven using essentially the same argument as in my answer.

Comment: @MoeHirsch   Dear  prof.  Hirsch,  Thank  you  very  much  for  your  answer and  the  reference to the  Annals paper.